# GitHub Desktop. Открывать файлы через "Visual Studio" а не через "Visual Studio Code"

Tags: visual-studio, github

Мучаюсь с проблемой. Я работаю с Unity и соответственно все проекты на C#. Работаю в "Visual Studio" и "Visual Studio Code" мне не удобна и не нужна. Но GitHub Desktop предлагает открывать файлы только через "Visual Studio Code".
Как настроить в GitHub Desktop открытие в "Visual Studio"?